# Why is glusterfs renaming files during rsync import?

Tags: rsync, glusterfs

While searching for an error after failed initial rsync of data to glusterfs I found the following entry in /var/log/glusterfs/data-nfs.log:

> [MSGID: 109066] [dht-rename.c:1410:dht_rename] 0-volume1-dht: renaming /source/**.filename.jpg.bWVXS4** (hash=volume1-replicate-0/cache=volume1-replicate-0) => /dest/filename.jpg (hash=volume1-replicate-0/cache=)

There is definatelly not a filename starting with a dot, I just double checked it. What is this entry about? There are thousands of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how rsync does its thing.  It writes the file to a temporary location (starting with a dot) and then when the file is completely written, it renames it to the final location.  It needs to keep the original file around because how rsync's algorithm works -- it reads chunks of the original file and interleaves them with changed data sent over the network.

You can avoid this behaviour by using the option `--inplace`, but it does terrible things to the incremental sync algorithm, if you're relying on that (rather than copying new files in).